# Trying to build the basic python extension example fails (windows)

Tags: python, c, build, distutils

I have Python 2.6 and Visual Studio 2008 running on a Win7 x64 machine.
When I try to build the basic python extension example in c "example_nt" as found in the python 2.6 sources distribution, it  fails:

```
python setup.py build
```

And this results in:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'aspell' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    ext_modules = [module1])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 343, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 469, in build_extensions
self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 448, in compile
self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 358, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 274, in query_vcvarsall
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

What can I do to fix this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Make sure you are running from the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" that has the appropriate environmental variables set, and that the version of Python you are using matches the bit-ness (32/64) of the compiler.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624507

Answer (score 3):

For Win7 x64 machine Python 2.6 (x64) machine, you need to install
Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
See the instructions at
http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows

The commercial Visual Studio 2008 is for Python 2.6, 2.7 and 2.8
on the 32-bit x86 setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid installing the Windows SDK and VS 2008 for this.

I believe the problem you have is due to VS 2008 not having the 64-bit compilers. To check this, find your directory containing vcvarsall.bat (search in the VS 2008 directory for it C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0). Once you've found vcvarsall.bat, open a cmd prompt in the directory it's in and type `.\vcvarsall.bat amd64`
If it is not the problem, you will see `Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x64 tools.`
If this is the problem, you will get back a message saying something about configuration. This is easy to fix.

The express version of VS does not have the 64-bit compilers. The solution is to also install the SDK but is messy and unreliable so MS have provided all the compilers together in a single download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Once you have downloaded the compilers, you can follow my post here if it doesn't work straight out the box:
[pyusb 2.7 windows install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304569/pyusb-2-7-windows-install-error/28500135#28500135)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.