# What's the best way to deploy flask application to windows based server

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I tried many attempt in installing flask app in windows. I found that mod_wsgi need to be installed along with apache, however, I can't get the latest mod_wsgi.so , any idea the easiest way to install flask in windows ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

See instructions for using `pip install mod_wsgi` in:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42307082/128141

Should work fine with Python 3. Has been one report of something not quite being right for Python 2.7 in generated configuration but can be manually fixed if that occurs. Better to use latest Python 3 anyway.

Comment: I've tried your solution to , but it caused error on my machine, it says like this,

 fatal error LNK1120: 101 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Are you sure you installed the correct MS compiler for Python version based on https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers You need to provide more information.

Comment: I used [link](http://www.ampps.com/) because I had difficulties in finding the mod_wsgi.so (dont understand how to change binary files to that) , and when I checked my compiler is visual c++ 2015. I just deleted everything and try to install it again from scratch using ordinary python installer , and try to do the `pip install mod_wsgi`

Comment: I tried to redo all of my process and still , the error is same

fatal error LNK1120: 101 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exi
t status 1120

it says something like this :-

 --compile failed with error cod
e 1 in C:\Users\dtk\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4t5i11z4\mod-wsgi\

and it also says 
 wsgi_apache.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
mod_wsgi.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Comment: You still haven't said what Python version you are using. Also what Apache distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 and latest apache 2.4 and using the right c++ compiler, also I tried using python 3.4 , still not work, really drives me crazy

Comment: But which Apache 2.4 distribution are you using? Some of them can't be used to build additional Apache modules. I recommend the one at https://www.apachelounge.com/ Also, what are the symbols the linker is saying are undefined?

Comment: I tried both from xampp and ampps , none of them worked, should I use the independent apache ? . I'll try to install the independent one. the linker says something similar like this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589617/linking-errors-when-compiling-python-extension-module)

Comment: Yes, use https://www.apachelounge.com/ Have heard of those others being problems in the past.