# Compiling Python 3.5 64 bit C Extension with third party library

Tags: c, python-3.x, dll, glfw, glew

### My Setup

I am trying to develop a Python 3 library as a C extension. I am on Windows 10, and I have Python 3.5.2 64 bit installed as my only Python distribution. I also have Visual Studio 2017 installed.

This library relies on glew and glfw. I believe I have installed the libraries properly, I've installed their headers in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\
```

their `.lib` files in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
```

and their `.dll` files in

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

My `setup.py` file looks essentially like this:

```
module = Extension('my_library',
                   library_dirs=['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib'],
                   libraries=['glew32', 'glfw3'],
                   sources=['my_library/c/my_library.c'])

setup(name="MyLibrary",
      version="0.1",
      description="My Python 3 Library",
      ext_modules=[module])
```

### The Problem

When I run `python setup.py build`, I receive

```
MSVCRT.lib(chkstk.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1112
```

Okay, so I'm really not sure what that means, as my machine is 64 bit... but it is x86 architecture. But I assumed that meant that I was not targeting 64 bit, so I read online and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624507/building-64-bit-c-python-extensions-on-windows), which says to run

```
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
set MSSdk=1
```

Using the "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt", which I don't have. I tried the other command prompts, and they either give the same error, or they give

```
Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
```

When I try the setting `DISTUTILS_USE_SDK` method on the regular command prompt, I receive the error

```
python\python35\include\pyconfig.h(68): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

### The Question

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I just want to be able to link the glew/glfw. The module was originally compiling and working properly when the glew/glfw were not being included/linked.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: You need to install the 64 bit versions of glew and glfw. Your architecture is `x86_64` not `x86`. In windows they call `x86_64` as `x64`.

Comment: I did install the 64 bit versions of glew and glfw. And yes you are correct, I guess I meant I had the x86 instruction set. I will reinstall the 64 bit versions just to be sure.

Comment: This is the error message `module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`. Clearly you have a mixed architecture.

Comment: I made sure the libraries installed are 64 bit. I also tried something new. I tried linking the libraries without having the source include them. Aka, the source doesn't need them, but I wanted to see if just linking them would cause any errors, and it did. I get `unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie` and `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup`. Please tell me if there is any more information you would like to know.

Comment: The error you are seeing means you didn't link it with `MSVCRT`. This will tell you all about it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/988ye33t.aspx

Comment: I added `msvcrt.lib` during the linking phase and I am still getting the same errors...

Comment: I found this solution from microsoft knowledegbase. This could resolve your original issue https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd11052014_333.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)

Comment: I found those as well, `vcvars64.bat` doesn't exist in the Visual Studio 14 installation. `vcvarsall.bat` exists with these options `x86 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_arm | amd64_x86 | amd64_arm`.

For the second link, I'm not using visual studio, I just want to understand everything through CLI before moving to an IDE.

Comment: Even with command line, you still need to set your environment variables to select the correct architecture. You should run vcvarsall.bat with x86_amd64 option.

Comment: Yes I have done this, that is what I meant by the previous comment. I receive the same error. I feel like I have set up the build tools incorrectly